# Are Delete and Backspace keys functioning related to data structures?

Tags: data-structures, keyboard

Can we say that the **delete** key works on **Stack** and **backspace** works on **Queue** datastructures ?
Are there any other keyboard functions that work on **datastructures** that everyone should know ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are just talking about using a keyboard to enter text into a text field, then if you aren't moving your cursor around it is like a stack of characters.  Hitting any character-key puts that letter on top of the stack, and hitting the backspace key pops the topmost character off of the stack.

Comment: It would depend on the software you are using.  What happens when you hit the delete key?

Comment: On moving the cursor to left of characters .. it deletes the first character typed.

Comment: If you are always using delete to remove the first added character, and only add characters on to the end of the text, then that is just like a queue!  Queues - First into the queue, first out of the queue.